# How can turn on vsync in gnome shell?

Tags: gnome, intel-graphics

That's my problem, I can not turn on vsync (or vertical synchronization) in gnome shell, so that videos are "choppy" vertically. I must say that I have a HD integrated graphics intel sandy bridge, in ubuntu with nvidia card is easily activated from the nvidia control panel. as I can do the same in intel? It also clarifies that I can enable compiz vsync from ccsm, but I find nothing in shell

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but ccsm is for compiz, and gnome-shell does not use compiz so it will be of no use to you.

Answer (score 3):

Intel driver has a good option for tear free rendering:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

under the Section device which use intel driver add the following option:

`Option      "TearFree"    "true"`

If you do not have the xorg.conf file you can easy generate them for you using nvidia-settings or using Xorg

Look at [this](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_xorg.conf)

I hope it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You should know about X.Org Server.

You can configure xorg to enable or disable vsync. You can define modeline without vsync: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding_undetected_resolutions

Maybe there are also Options for vsync (so you can change vsync for all modes) but I'm not sure about this.

Also make sure that you have [`vaapi`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Acceleration_API) enabled and `libva` installed